# Do the Sliders ever visit the same world twice?

Tags: sliders

We see the Sliders briefly return to their home world in Exodus I/II. Is this the only example of the Sliders visiting the same world twice?

Comment: Or was it their home world . . . or one very _very_ like it?!?!?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Yes, they return to Earth Prime, the dimension of their origin several times across the series. Earth Prime is the Earth that the Sliders originate from, although it is learned in Genesis that Quinn Mallory actually was not born on this earth. The series revolves around the Sliders quest to return to "Earth Prime".**

### [Returning to "Earth Prime"](http://sliders.wikia.com/wiki/Earth_Prime)

**From the Sliders Wikia:**

- In "Into the Mystic" they encounter Quinn's double who is able to send them home. On their arrival they learn they have only seconds to decide if this is in fact home. The decision rests on a squeaky gate. When it doesn't squeak the Sliders believe that they have not found their home and slide away. (It was Earth Prime, someone oiled the gate.)
- Rembrandt and Wade are convinced that the earth they slide into in "Earth Prime" but when it is discovered that this San Francisco has the Azure Gate Bridge instead of the Golden Gate Bridge they realize that they have found **[Earth Double Prime](http://sliders.wikia.com/wiki/Earth_Double_Prime)**.
- In "[The Exodus](http://sliders.wikia.com/wiki/The_Exodus)" while Quinn and Maggie are screening potential Earths, they come across "Earth Prime" but are unable to stay as Maggie is unable to breath its atmosphere.
- The third time the Sliders are able to make it home they find that "Earth Prime" has been invaded by the [Kromaggs](http://sliders.wikia.com/wiki/Kromagg). This spawns a new quest to find a weapon to eject the Kromaggs from their home.
- "In The Seer", the series finale, a psychic believes that their next slide, although will return Rembrandt home, will also kill them. This earth has a biological weapon that defeated the Kromaggs, and Rembrandt slides with it but his fate and the fate of "Earth Prime" is unknown.

Comment: Is Earth Prime the only world they repeatedly return to?

Comment: As far as I could tell watching the series. It was the only place they WANTED to be going and making an effort to find. The nature of their technology almost always assured they would NOT be returning to the same planet twice. It wasn't until we were aware that people had effectively harnessed this technology that we understood it was possible to map your progress from continuum to continuum.

Comment: @ahsteele Depends on if you want different episodes/persons or not.  At the beginning of 2x06, [Summer of Love](http://sliders.wikia.com/wiki/Summer_of_Love), the timer successfully opens a portal to the same Earth twice.  Two go through the first time, the other two go through the second time.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the answers already provided, they return once to the world of the 'Exodus' refugees in 'Dinoslide', and also slide away from and back to the 'Prophet' world in Season 4 episode [Prophets and Loss](https://earthprime.com/episode-guide/prophets-and-loss):

*'Cadmus returns the timer to the Sliders and reveals himself as a mole. The Sliders slide but decide to return so that Samson can carry on the fight.'*

Both these instances are thanks to Dr Stephen Jensen's upgrading of the Egyptian Timer in The Exodus.

Comment: Thanks for the edit Mooz will format links thus in future :)

Comment: Exodus Part 1 is when the timer first gains the ability to remember visited worlds and follow the trail of other Sliders. https://earthprime.com/episode-guide/the-exodus-part-1

From that point on, there are various intentional returns to the same world.